# WordPress > htaccess > redirect directory and all its sub-directories to one directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a directory and all its sub-directories to another location with a single redirect rule within wordpress´ htaccess file?

e.g.

```
http://example.com/old
http://example.com/old/foo
http://example.com/old/foo/bar
```

move them all to

```
http://example.com/new
```

--

when I try this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old/(.*)$ /new/
```

while pointing to

```
http://example.com/old/foo/bar
```

it ends up with

```
http://example.com/new/bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this rule in your htaccess (**before** Wordpress' main rule, after `RewriteEngine On` line)

```
RewriteRule ^old(/.*)?$ /new [R=301,L]
```

Note: you may have to clear your browser cache since your old rule is stored into it